# Local scope in C

Tags: c, scope, cs50

I have something like this in C:

```
string getCipherText(string text, int key) {
    string cipherText = "";
    printf("Plaintext: %s, key: %i\n", text, key);

    key = key % 26;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        if ((text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') || (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')) {
            text[i] = (int) text[i] + key;
        }
        cipherText +=  text[i];
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Why is my returning cipherText string empty? Isn't it the same variable in for loop? It's cloud IDE from EdX https://ide.cs50.io where they have a string type in [cs50.h](https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/?highlight=string#c.string)

Comment: Is this really C (probably with `cs50.h`), not C++?

Comment: Which is the definition for type "string"?

Comment: You can't go appending to strings like that in C.  Anyone would think you'd learned a scripting language before learning C, where such manipulation is possible.  C is not like that.  You have to allocate memory for your string.  You allocate a pointer to read-only memory, which will likely give trouble when you play around with its contents.

Comment: It is cs50, I think it is C what we are learning. It's their cloud IDE. They have their own string type in cs50.h

Comment: Also, `text[i] + key;` is likely a problem when the sum is more than 127.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix CS50 defines `char*` as `string` which is some serious trolling. I'm starting to become concerned about how much damage CS50 is doing to people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are modifying the contents of the "text" parameter directly, you could remove all references to the "ciphertext" variable, and just

```
return text;
```

at the end. This has the benefit that the "text" string already exists in the calling function, and is definitely in scope of that calling function.

Comment: The simplest solution for me. Thanks! And thanks to the others for explaining buffer and what string type is.

Comment: I see what you did there, but it violates the principle of least surprise.  Returning a string suggests that it is a *new* string, not the same one you passed in.  The "proper" technique for modifying a string in-place is to simply return nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `string` is an alias to `char*`, `cipherText +=  text[i];` is not concatenating strings but moving the pointer.

You should allocate a buffer and store the result there like this:

```
string getCipherText(string text, int key) {
    size_t len = strlen(text):
    string cipherText = malloc(len + 1);
    if (cipherText == NULL) {
        fputs("malloc() failed!\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("Plaintext: %s, key: %i\n", text, key);

    key = key % 26;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if ((text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') || (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z')) {
            text[i] = (int) text[i] + key;
        }
        cipherText[i] =  text[i];
    }
    cipherText[len] = '\0';
    return cipherText;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is C, then C does not have a type `string` in the language.

It can be created via `typedef` or other "trickery".

But the language does **not** support using `+=` to concatenate strings together like this:

```
cipherText +=  text[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the name `string` means the following typedef name

```
typedef char *string;
```

Thus in this declaration

```
string cipherText = "";
```

there is declared a pointer to the string literal `""`.

So in this statement

```
cipherText +=  text[i];
```

the pointer pointing to the string literal `""` is incremented by the integer value of `text[i]` using the pointer arithmetic. That is the pointer points to nowhere.There is no valid object where the pointer points. As a result the function invokes undefined behavior.

Also there is another bug in this statement

```
text[i] = (int) text[i] + key;
```

because the expression in the right hand side can result in overflow of the type char if it behaves as the type signed char.

In any case the implementation does not correspond to the function  declaration.

The function declaration means that the passed string must be changed "in place" without creating any other character array.

Otherwise the function parameter shall be declared like `const char *text` because in the case when a modified copy of the original string is created the original string itself is not modified.